# A database design technique

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I am solving a problem where I need to store items. The item can be made from various sub-items. Items would have attributes like name, sum of prices of all sub-items. Sub-items would have attributes like color, shape, price and name.

I have thought of a very basic approach and would like to know if this is efficient.
The idea is to have one database table where each row would contain ItemId, ItemName and sub-item attributes. The primary key would be combination of ItemId and SubItemName.

The most frequent operations are fetching details of sub-item Y of an item X.

Somehow, I feel this approach is not clean. Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Comment: You mean there are different items and each item has id, name then each item has its sub item that contains sub-item id, item_id, color, shape, price. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. And each item can have multiple sub-items

Comment: Please clear more I am assuming there is an item then one item has many sub-items is that correct?

Comment: Yes. But there can be many items as well

Comment: wait please I am designing this database for you but please don't forget to mark my answer or vote up. I am actively replying answers but 10% of my answers marked even users are saying that's worked and thanks. that's all

Comment: I will be more than happy to upvote and accept the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer:
[image]

1. You can store different categories for items in item_category table
2. items table will store as many items as you want
3. Each item will have many sub items in Sub_items table

You can increase or decrease the columns

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

This is called a bill of materials. You need one table of parts/items, and one table which stores the relationship between fathers and sons (or in your terminology, items and sub-items). The point is that your sub-item can have sub-items of its own, which the above table design allows. It's not clear whether the accepted answer allows this.